# GitPython: set git executable at runtime

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I would like to use GitPython in the following scenario:

- Download and extract a portable git (e.g. one of [these](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.20.1.windows.1))
- Use this git executable to clone a repository

I want to use the portable git, no matter if git is already installed or not (the reason being [this issue](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/871#issuecomment-489618051)).

---

I know i can specify the git executable by setting the `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` environment variable, but

1. i've not found a way to do this on windows (`setx` seems to do *something*, but `env` shows no such variable afterward) apart from manually editing the system environment variables.
2. This is supposed to be an end-user program, i cannot ship instructions like "please set an environment variable".
3. The path is only known when the program is already running.

So my question is, how can i set the executable path manually during runtime? The following does not seem to work, it only prints `git` and my system's git version:

```py
import os
import sys

# Download and extract a portable git

git_dir = r"C:\Users\Florian\Downloads\mingit-busybox\cmd"
git_bin = os.path.join(git_dir, "git")

os.putenv("GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE", git_bin)
os.environ.putenv("GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE", git_bin)

# Attempt with VonC's Answer, making sure that it is first in PATH
sys.path = [git_dir] + sys.path
os.pathsep.join([git_dir]) + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]

# Only import git now, because that's when the path is checked!
import git
g = git.Git()
print(g.GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE)
print(".".join([str(v) for v in g.version_info]))
```

```sh
❯ python .\gitpython_test.py
git
2.23.0 # My portable git version is 2.20.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if, in addition of setting, you could set the PATH.
See "[how to set `PATH=%PATH%` as environment in Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36549536/6309)"

The goal is to set `PATH` to `C:\Users\Florian\Downloads\mingit-busybox\cmd;%PATH%`, meaning the `git` from `mingit-busybox` would come *first*.

Here's a minimal example:

```
git_dir = r"C:\Users\Florian\Downloads\mingit-busybox\cmd"
# Make sure it's at the beginning of the PATH
os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join([git_dir]) + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
# NOW import it
import git
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like it could work. I will give it a try, expect a reply in ~10h

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you! i *only* had to set the path, no need to do anything else

Comment: so, i'm not sure how to phrase it, but... this ain't it. Apparently my earlier attempts had set the right environment variable, but at the time the program didn't recognize it (shell not restarted or whatever). The next day when i tried your suggestion, it worked... but once i removed the environment variable, it did not. Sorry for that. Apparently `os.environ` is reset every time it's imported - I'll continue to investigate

Comment: @MCO Did you set the path as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36549536/6309? And can you edit the question with the exact Python code you use?

Comment: i updated the example in the question with my code. it's a bit different than the answer you linked, to make sure the path is *first* in the PATH. i checked with a debugger, and while in my code the value is in fact in the PATH, but in GitPython's \_\_init__.py the path is back to "normal", supposedly because they reimported `os`

Comment: updated the example again, to reflect an important detail - GitPython checks its environment variables on import, so it should be imported after setting them.

Comment: Aaaaand the award for the stupidest programmer goes to...
if you check the example thoroughly, you can spot my mistake... right around the os.pathsep magic. i'll submit an edit to your answer to make up for it, but you were right all along! woo!

Comment: @MCO I was about to comment ;) But we have all been there.